# Slow scrollview with background image

Tags: android, xml

How should I set background image for layout with scroolview, because when I add imageView to below code, scroolview start working very slow. Image has 700kb. If i set `android:background="@drawable/background04"` to relativeLayout scroolview also work very slow.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.scrollview.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/background04"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView6" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView7" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView8" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView9" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView10" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Edit:**

For testing I use htc desire 820.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.aapps.scrollview">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Logcat:

```
05-03 10:48:04.750 17843-17891/com.aapps.scrollview E/OpenGLRenderer: CacheDebug: generateTexture() in TextureCache::get(, if (!texture): bitmap = 0x55a971acb0
05-03 10:48:04.750 17843-17891/com.aapps.scrollview E/OpenGLRenderer: CacheDebug: generateTexture() in TextureCache::get(, if (!texture): pixelRef ID = 415
05-03 10:48:05.250 17843-17891/com.aapps.scrollview E/OpenGLRenderer: CacheDebug: generateTexture() in TextureCache::get(, if (!texture): bitmap = 0x55a971acb0
05-03 10:48:05.250 17843-17891/com.aapps.scrollview E/OpenGLRenderer: CacheDebug: generateTexture() in TextureCache::get(, if (!texture): pixelRef ID = 415
05-03 10:48:05.850 17843-17891/com.aapps.scrollview E/OpenGLRenderer: CacheDebug: generateTexture() in TextureCache::get(, if (!texture): bitmap = 0x55a971acb0
05-03 10:48:05.850 17843-17891/com.aapps.scrollview E/OpenGLRenderer: CacheDebug: generateTexture() in TextureCache::get(, if (!texture): pixelRef ID = 415
05-03 10:48:06.330 17843-17891/com.aapps.scrollview E/OpenGLRenderer: CacheDebug: generateTexture() in TextureCache::get(, if (!texture): bitmap = 0x55a971acb0
05-03 10:48:06.330 17843-17891/com.aapps.scrollview E/OpenGLRenderer: CacheDebug: generateTexture() in TextureCache::get(, if (!texture): pixelRef ID = 415
05-03 10:48:06.840 17843-17843/com.aapps.scrollview I/Choreographer: Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: try with adding this android:largeHeap="true" in your application tag in manifest

Comment: and read this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

put the background in your parent Layout Container

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background04"
tools:context="com.example.scrollview.MainActivity">
```

and remove the ImageView because its not needed anymore

another tip in your code, you're using too much `alignParent`, you can have the same output when you make match parent the width and height and remove all the alignParent property. see below code changes

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:src="@drawable/background04"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.scrollview.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView4" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView5" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView6" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView7" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView8" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView9" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView10" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: and close parent Layout Container with `</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: @hrskrs ofcourse, that is not needed to be said anymore ahahaha

Comment: As i said in question if i do like this also work slow.

Comment: @DomenJakofčič what device did you use to test it? also can you post your manifest file?

Comment: also add the logcat, it shows status of your memory if it takes too much memory

Comment: @DomenJakofčič i tried my code above and use an HD wallpaper for background and its working fine. I use genymotion Emulator OS version lollipop

Comment: thanks for your help. Problem was with size of picture, i reduce size to 100kb and now is working well.